# Precalc find the solution set

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

Find the solution set $$\left|\frac{2}{3}x-6\right|=2$$

The solution is $$x=6,12$$

Looking for some help finding this solution, do I need to consider $x$ from two ends?

Comment: Notice that $\left| \dfrac{2}{3} x - 6 \right| = 2$ means $\dfrac{2}{3} x - 6 = \pm 2$. This gives the solutions you mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever there is an absolute value equation you can consider it to be two equations. If $$\frac23 x-6\geq 0$$
then
$$\frac23x-6 = 2$$
since $|y|=y$ if $y\geq 0$, and if
$$\frac23x-6<0$$
then
$$6-\frac23x=2$$
since $|y| = -y$ if $y<0$. You can see by solving each of these that you get the desired results.

Comment: why did you switch the signs in the second case?

Comment: @user Because if $y<0$ then $|y|=-y$.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if $\displaystyle \left | \frac{2}{3}x-6 \right| = 2$, then $\displaystyle \frac{2}{3}x-6 =-2\quad (x=6)\;$ or  $\;\displaystyle \frac{2}{3}x-6 =2 \quad(x=12)$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Consider the cases:
$$\dfrac23x-6\geq 0$$ and you will get $$\frac{2}{3}x-6=2$$ in the other case you will have
$$-\frac{2}{3}x+6=2$$

Comment: why did you switch the signs in the second case

Comment: in the other case $\frac23x-6<0$ so $|\frac23x-6|=-(\frac23-6)$

Answer (score 0):

The equality is equivalent to $|x-9|=3$.  And now read that out loud: "The distance from $x$ to $9$ equals $3$." There are obviously exactly two numbers satisfying that equation.